# Pierpont pseudoprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A Pierpont number is of the form $ p=2^a.3^b+1$. (I used a>0)

Trying to explore them, I did a very simple loop to test for primality:

loop on g over primes

- if $g^{p-1}\mod p \neq 1$, then p is not prime (Fermat's little theorem)
- else if order of g is p-1, then p is prime (can be easily checked as p-1 has at most two prime divisors, 2 and 3)
- else try next prime for g (either g is not a generator for prime p or p is a pseudo prime for base g)

Surprisingly, almost all Pierpont non prime numbers can be detected with g=2. For numbers < $10^{360}$, I only found 8 pseudoprime Pierpont numbers for base 2. 6 of them are not pseudoprimes for 3, 1 of them is pseudo prime for 2,3 and 5 (but not 7) and one (small) is pseudo prime for 2,3, 5, 7, 11 (but not 13).

Also 2 and 3 are rarely generators for Pierpont primes, while 5 seems to be very often.
I was wondering if there was more precise results on all of that somewhere. Can it be proven that at some point, larger Pierpont numbers can't be pseudoprimes for base 2 (making primality test almost trivial on them)?

Edit: no pseudoprimes for 2 found from $10^{360}$ to $10^{500}$.

Comment: What about the composite fermat-numbers ? They should be fermat-pseudoprime with respect to base $2$.

Comment: The two numbers you mentioned that are neither pseudoprime to base $2$ nor to base $3$ are Carmichael-numbers and my guess is that the other $2$-pseudoprimes are the composite Fermat-numbers and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to note here:

**(1)** By quadratic reciprocity, when $a>2$, $\left( \frac{2}{p}\right)=1$, for $p$ a Pierpont prime. Thus $$2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=1\mod p$$ for $a>2$ and thus $2$ is not a generator for $p$.

A similar result holds for $a>1$, $b>0$ and the base of $3$.

However, for the base $5$, quadratic reciprocity often gives
$$5^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=-1\mod p$$
(For example when $a=b$) and thus $5$ often is a generator for $p$ (have to check some cubic reciprocity too).

(2) For why pseudoprimes are rare for base $2$, I’m not entirely convinced it’s for any reason other than well, (Fermat) pseudoprimes are usually rare.

Have you determined that pseudoprimes are more common for a base of $5$ say (rather than starting at $2$ and only then checking $5$)?

Edit: as mentioned in the comments here is a probable counterexample: all Fermat numbers ($a=2^k, b=0$) $$2^{2^k}+1$$ are pseudoprime to base $2$ if composite (and actually overpseudoprime), but after the first few $k$, all known examples are composite.